# Does the Necklace of Prayer Beads allow two spells to be cast in a round?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The Necklace of Prayer Beads states that it allows casting certain spells as a Bonus Action.

Can a memorized spell be cast as an Action - or do the normal rules apply in that only cantrips are allowed as a main action when using the Necklace of Prayer Beads?

Comment: There is only one way to cast 2 spells in a single round and it requires action surge

Comment: @GarretGang There's a heck of a lot more than that!  Thief's reflexes, *Time Stop*,  *Contingency*, legendary actions, reactions, *Glyph of Warding*, cantrips, etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### There is no rules exception for same-round casting of spells from magic items.

In the DMG, under "Activating Magic Items", it says...

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, **doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots, and requires no components unless the item’s description says otherwise.** The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration. **Certain items make exceptions to these rules, changing the casting time, duration, or other parts of a spell.**

Other than the fact that they do not require components or slots (first bold section above), spells cast from items are no different from casting them normally... unless the magic item specifically calls it out (second bold section).

The *[Necklace of Prayer Beads](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/necklace-of-prayer-beads)* specifies a reduced casting time for the spells it contains, but that's it. If it were meant to bypass any of the other spellcasting rules, it would say so.

Comment: It would help to mention what the general spellcasting rule is. You can't cast two spells in a round.

Comment: @BobTheAverage The question itself already mentions it.

Answer (score 7):

## They do not - the normal rules apply.

Prayer Beads specify *you* are casting the spell:

> Each bead contains a spell that **you can cast** from it as a Bonus Action (using your spell save DC if a save is necessary).

Since you are casting the spell, the normal rules for spells cast with a Bonus Acton apply;

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on Your Turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

This would not be the case if the item were casting the Bonus Action spell rather than you - however in this case it's clear you are the caster.

Answer (score 2):

The beads do not provide an exception to the general rule. The description of the beads would explicitly say so if they did.